# Create an xml file using sp_OACreate in SQL Server but XML Parser issue occurred (on first two charecter of the file)

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've been searching for days on a solution for the problem I have.

I have created a xml file using `sp_OACreate` in SQL Server. Physically I cannot see any unwanted character or space on the file (first 2 character). While parsing I am facing an xml parser issue. If the same content has been typed manually then there is no issue.

while parsing, parser shows this error:

[image: while parsing, parser shows this error]

This is the stored procedure:

```
IF(ISNULL(@String,'') != '')
BEGIN
    SET @String = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,'&','&amp;'),'"','&quot;'),'`','&quot;'),'''','&apos;')  
END 

SET @String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><'+@MethodName+'Response><PROJECTS>' + @String+ '</PROJECTS>
<RESULT>true</RESULT>
<MESSAGE>Success</MESSAGE>
</'+@MethodName+'Response></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'

select @strErrorMessage='opening the File System Object'  
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.File SystemObject' , @objFileSystem OUT  

Select @FileAndPath=@path+'\'+@filename  
    if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objFileSystem , @strErrorMessage='Creating file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'  
    if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod   @objFileSystem   , 'CreateTextFile' , @objTextStream OUT, @FileAndPath,2,True  

    if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, @strErrorMessage='writing to the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'  
    if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Write', Null, @String  

    if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, @strErrorMessage='closing the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'  
    if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Close'  

    if @hr<>0  
    begin  
    Declare   
        @Source varchar(255),  
        @Description Varchar(255),  
        @Helpfile Varchar(255),  
        @HelpID int  

        EXECUTE sp_OAGetErrorInfo  @objErrorObject, @source output,@Description output,@Helpfile output,@HelpID output  
        Select @strErrorMessage='Error whilst ' +coalesce(@strErrorMessage,'doing something') +', '+coalesce(@Description,'')  
        raiserror (@strErrorMessage,16,1)  
    end  
EXECUTE  sp_OADestroy @objTextStream  
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
```

How should I change my SP to prevent the parser error?

Comment: Seems like your XML parser can't deal with **UTF-8** encoding in files, and doesn't like the byte-order mark (BOM) bytes at the beginning of an UTF-8 file. Shame on that XML parser! UTF-8 definitely **IS** widely acceptable encoding these days, any serious piece of software ought to support it

Comment: You could change the final argument of `CreateTextFile` so that it writes it as ASCII rather than Unicode (with BOM, which there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent it adding) but I'd second marc's implicit suggestion - look to replace whatever is parsing this XML and cannot cope with the BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer finally. what the problem is by default SQL server written file as **UCS-2 BOM** encoding. so that while parsing the unwanted characters are shown.

I have rectified this while download the file, i have changed encoding type as **UTF-8** then will give the file.
now the problem solved.

Thanks to all for your valuable comments on this.